# quick look up data on typing in textbox using knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i want to create a quick look up on entering some text in textbox using knockout.js. i.e whenever the user types in the textbox the related data to entered string in text box displayed in the form of dropdown under the textbox. can anybody tell me how can i achive this functionality ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can force the value mutation after key down:

```
<input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

There is a complete code example on the [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) homepage:

```
<p>Your value: <input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>You have typed: <span data-bind="text: someValue"></span></p> <!-- updates in real-time -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        someValue: ko.observable("edit me")
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code:

```
var VM = function () {

    this.text = ko.observable('');

    this.suggestionStrings = [
        'Hello',
        'world',
        'name',
        'richard'
    ];

    this.suggestions = ko.computed(function () {

        var text = this.text();

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.suggestionStrings, function (str) {
            return new RegExp(text, 'i').test(str);
        });
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/badsyntax/f8aCY/